# Wordpress admin display post type tags as checkbox

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I used Wordpress ACF plugin to created a post type called `resource`, also I created two tag categories named `resource-type` and `resource-topic`, I can added in those tags in the post by the enter certain key in input box, but if the input is mistype, a new tag will auto added in the list, this is not what I want and I think of make the tags as checkbox so that it would easily know what tags is available and reduce the mistype error, is it possible to change like this way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered changing them to Categories? Categories and Tags are essentially the same thing, just that Categories have a Hierarchy. Category selection is via a Checkbox so you will have more control over what is selected.

**Update**
If you have used the function 'register_taxonomy' to create your Tags then you only need to add or adjust one variable - 'hierarchical' - which needs to be set to true. See: [Codex information on register_taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/)

If you used a plugin to create the Taxonomies it should have a similar option. Remember to backup your website before you make any changes.

Comment: Yes I wanted those tags can be display as checkbox, can it be achieve?

Comment: I have updated my answer for you, hope it helps!

Comment: How can I make the existing "tags" taxonomy hierarchical?